# Castle Windsor inject multiple instances with one command

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have a lot of classes in the same namespace implementing the same interface.
if I want to inject these classes I need to explicitly declare command per instance.

```
namespace AllClasses{

 public class A<Brand> : IValidatable<Brand>{
 }

 public class B<Customer> : IValidatable<Customer>{
 }

 public class C<User> : IValidatable<User>{
 }

 public class D<Campaign> : IValidatable<Campaign>{
 }

}


public class INeedInjection{
   public INeedInjection(IValidatable<User> uv){}

}
```

Is there anyway to inject all the above classes (A,B,C,D) with single command?

Thanks

**UPDATE 1**
There are around 25 classes implementing `IValidatable`, I dont want to write explicit injection per implementation.  all the implementors are very similar, so I just assumed maybe there is wildcard command for that.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you looking to insert a list of all "implementors" instead of the single instance your `INeedInjection` class requires currently?

Comment: The correct terminology is "batch registration", that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register all `IValidatables` in an assembly using the `Types` class;

The example registers all classes implementing `IValidatable<T>` in the *current assembly* at once, but other methods on `Types` allows you to choose any other assembly to register from;

```
_container.Register(
    Types.FromThisAssembly()
         .BasedOn(typeof (IValidatable<>))
         .WithService.Base());
```

Comment: I dont understand, you still have 2 commands for each implementation (A and B), in my case 25 commands. I am looking for single command if possible, thanks

Comment: @SexyMF Hm, in other words, you mean "I dont want to write explicit _registration_ per implementation", not as you say, "I dont want to write explicit injection per implementation"?

Comment: @SexyMF Updated the answer to cover registration instead.